# rails_sql_views error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use migrations to manage my SQL Server views.  I found the rails_sql_views extension and it looks like exactly what I need, but I'm getting an error when running the migration that I cant figure out. Here is the error:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
uninitialized constant CreateFunds
```

Here is my migration:

```
class CreateFundView < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_view :v_funds, "SELECT * from funds"
  end

  def down
    drop_view :v_funds
  end
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.1. 
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Missing a "s" in the class name? Or class name do not match migration file name?

Comment: Checked all that.  Here is a stacktrace if that helps;  https://gist.github.com/1371954

Comment: Are you sure? I would guess that your migration file is named something like `db/migrate/20111117101626_create_funds.rb` and the migration class in that file is named `CreateFundView` but rails expects to find a class name `CreateFunds`. So either rename the migration file or change the class name so they match up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, I upgraded the rails_sql_views gem to one that was Rails 3.1.1 compatible.
(at least I think that's what fixed it!).  Here is a link to the gem that is working:

https://github.com/mremolt/rails_sql_views.git

Here is a working migration:

```
class CreateFundView < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
create_view :funds,
            "SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT
              FUND.FUND_ID AS [fund_id],
              FUND.DESCRIPTION AS [fund_description],
              FUND_FUND_CATEGORY.LONGDESCRIPTION AS [fund_category],
              FUND.NOTES AS [fund_notes]
              FROM
                RE7.dbo.FUND AS FUND LEFT OUTER JOIN
                RE7.dbo.TABLEENTRIES AS FUND_FUND_CATEGORY ON FUND.FUND_CATEGORY = FUND_FUND_CATEGORY.TABLEENTRIESID
              WHERE     (FUND.FUNDTYPE = 23702)
              ORDER BY [fund_description]"
  end

  def down
    drop_view :funds
  end
end
```